# Is there any way with commands, to have 2 Armories on your house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I recently bought the Hearthfire DLC and built my house, but there was no way to have an armory on both sides of the house through crafting, and now i wanted to ask, if there is some sort of command or cheat, to get myself a second Armory.

Comment: I'm assuming you're playing on PC?

Comment: Thats 'Hearthfire' DLC for next time.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to have 2 armories in one house. Hearthfire buildings are collections of disabled world objects that get enabled when built by the player, in order for a second armory to be buildable it would need to have been prepared by Bethesda and included in the DLC.

If you're not satisfied by vanilla and DLC housing options in Skyrim, you should take a look at the [available mods](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/categories/67/) - some of them surpass Bethesda's creations in every way.

Comment: Additional player homes are also available for the XBox One, and PS4 on [Bethesda's site](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim?category=Homes)